# Word for combining a score/value/etc. into another one

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What word can be used when we want to say that we combine a score/value/etc. into another one? For example, "we combine the scores of the test into the overall score of the user."

Some possible candidates may be: combine, integrate, interpolate, mix, fuse, and merge.

Comment: Actually, "combine" is probably the best word, unless it's a simple sum, in which case you can just say "add" or "add up."

Answer (score 1):

When talking about scores in particular, I would tend to use, and often see (in tests, sports etc), the word ***aggregate***.